# VB.NET - Form Execution stop after ExecuteScalar

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

It worked fine till i applicated some conditions... Now my form execution stop right after a ExecuteScalar... Any Ideas? Here is my code:

```
       Dim IDNomina As String = Format(Date.Now, "ddMMyyyy")

        conn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")
        connCalc = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")
        connActualizar = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=arj;")
        myCommand.Connection = conn

        If Date.Now.Day <> 14 And Date.Now.Day <> 15 And Date.Now.Day <> 28 And Date.Now.Day <> 29 And Date.Now.Day <> 30 Then
            MessageBox.Show("La nómina no puede ser generada ya que no se encuentra en días de pago")
            Me.Close()
        Else
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(IDNomina) FROM Nomina WHERE left(cast(`IDEmpleado` as char(10)), 8) = ?IDNomina"
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?IDNomina", IDNomina)

            conn.Open()
            Dim Ejecucion As Object = myCommand.ExecuteScalar '<--- Here is where execution stops and open the incomplete form
            conn.Close()
            If IsDBNull(Ejecucion) Then
...
```

Comment: Do you receive any kind of error/exception that might shed more light on the problem?

Comment: My crystal ball says that this code is called by the form's Load event and that you run this on a 64-bit operating system.  Change the Platform target to AnyCPU or tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions in the Debug + Exceptions dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely with the declaration of your parameter.

Try changing the following lines:

```
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(IDNomina) FROM Nomina WHERE left(cast(`IDEmpleado` as char(10)), 8) = ?IDNomina"
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?IDNomina", IDNomina)
```

to:

```
        myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(IDNomina) FROM Nomina WHERE left(cast('IDEmpleado' as char(10)), 8) = @IDNomina"
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNomina", IDNomina)
```

In addition, add a try/catch handler so that you can see what additional errors, if any, are being reported.

**Update**

Thanks to [the link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html) provided by [Miika L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025176/miika-l), the above will only work for versions prior to MySQL 5.0 unless `old syntax=yes` is added to the connection string. If you are using a pre-5.0 version, this is the syntax that you will need to use; otherwise, your original syntax is correct and you have a problem elsewhere in the code.

One thing to note: the quotes around IDEmpleado could possibly be causing problems, but you need to find out exactly where and which error is occurring.

Comment: He appears to be using MySQL, which I believe uses ? as the parameter symbol.

Comment: @MiikaL. Based on the MySQL documentation, it actually appears that they use the @ approach. Here is a link to some documentation from the MySQL site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-net-programming-blob.html

Comment: I found the following: "Note.  Prior versions of the provider used the '@' symbol to mark parameters in SQL. This is incompatible with MySQL user variables, so the provider now uses the '?' symbol to locate parameters in SQL." from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html But I am not sure what is the right answer actually. Is this something that has changed back and forth in MySQL?

Comment: Wow, they certainly did change it! That's pretty incredible (and an excellent find, by the way).

Comment: But the link I found was for 5.0, and there is now a version 5.6, for which I could neither confirm or deny which is the right method, as the examples used some of parameter array instead...

Answer (score 0):

Extract the SQL and run it in Management Studio/your SQL tool of choice and see what error, if any, is generated.